# OpenGL ES 2.0: Object flattens as it rotates

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

I have a problem. I'm rotating an object on screen with OpenGL ES 2.0 on a Raspberry Pi. Part of the rotation seems to work fine but the other part completly flattens the object out? I have tried 2 rotation functions so far with the exact same result. The depth buffer is also enabled and setup. I'm starting to think my projection matrix might be the problem here but I'm not sure. There's too much code to post right now, I will update this question with code when someone can narrow down where this behavior could come from.

Here's a video of the aforementioned problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mDMG7Eypj4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That video is private. But a knee-jerk guess: are you generating the rotation matrix entirely afresh every frame or are you mutating an existing matrix?

Comment: @Tommy I'm generating from an identity matrix every frame.

Comment: @Tommy Video was also changed to public.

Comment: @ReX357 are u using culling ?

Comment: @whiteFang I wasn't no but I tried using it just now and it made things worse.

Comment: @ReX357  enable depth_testing

Comment: @whiteFang it's already enabled with a 24 bit buffer, a depth range of 1.0f to 10.0f, a depth function of GL_LEQUAL and I clear the depth buffer bit every frame before rendering.

Comment: what you're using for drawing GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP ? or GL_TRIANGLES may be the problem is with your vertices: try GL_LINES oR GL_LINE_STRIP to debug.

Comment: @whiteFangs I use GL_TRIANGLES. I double rendered with GL_LINES as well and still can't understand what exactly is going on. At this point I think I might have to specify some kind of normals because from what I see the backface culling is removing a lot of geometry as it rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my issue finally... I had written the matrix multiplication function myself. Problem is I was assigning multiplication to one of the original matrices resulting in warped results down the rows.

```
void matrix_multiply(GLfloat * matrix1, GLfloat * matrix2) {

    matrix1[0] = matrix1[0] * matrix2[0] + matrix1[4] * matrix2[1] ... // etc

    [...]

    matrix1[4] = matrix1[0] * matrix2[4] + ... //etc

}
```

Now if you noticed, the value of matrix1[0] had already changed and been reassigned.

Rookie mistake.